# KeyListener inheritance in recongzing textarea object

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jtextarea, keylistener

My java code below is trying to do a keyListener inheritance. The problem is the private static JTextArea jt; is not being recognized in class CustomKeyListener. I dont know what I thought the 2 classes were connected by jt.addKeyListener(new CustomKeyListener()); but it is not being connected. My code is not compiling.

```
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 



class text11 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{ /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    // JFrame 
    static JFrame f; 



    // text area 
    private static JTextArea jt; 

    // main class 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        // create a new frame to store text field and button 
        f = new JFrame("textfield"); 

        // create a label to display text 




        // create a object of the text class 
        text11 te = new text11(); 



        // create a text area, specifying the rows and columns 
        jt = new JTextArea(" ", 20, 20); 

        JPanel p = new JPanel(); 

        // add the text area and button to panel 
        p.add(jt); 

        f.add(p); 
        // set the size of frame 
        f.setSize(300, 300); 
        jt.addKeyListener(new CustomKeyListener());

        f.show(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         jt.addKeyListener(new CustomKeyListener());

    }



    }

class CustomKeyListener implements KeyListener{
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
       if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){


           jt.setText(jt.getText() + "     sam");
       }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }   
 }
```

Comment: 1) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`. 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not best practice but you could change `jt` to be `public static JTextArea jt;` and then call it in your `CustomKeyListener` class with `text11.jt`

For example: `text11.jt.setText(text11.jt.getText() + "     sam");`